# Necesito Modificar el maxlength de un Input segun su primer carácter digitado

Tags: javascript, html, html5, dom

Tengo un input en un formulario que necesito modificar su maxlength según el primer carácter digitado. Las condiciones del input son las siguientes.

1. Los caracteres aceptados son "BE0123456789".
2. El primer carácter debe ser B o E no puede ser otro.
3. Si el primer carácter es B el maxlength del input debe ser 11 no puede ser menor ni puede ser mayor, debe ser igual a 11.
4. Si el primer carácter es E el maxlength del input debe ser 13 no puede ser menor ni puede ser mayor, debe ser igual a 13.
5. La letra B o E solo debe estar una sola vez y ser el primer carácter

```js
$("input[name=NCF_606]").on('input', function() {
  $(".alert").remove();

  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^BE0-9]/g, '');

  num = this.value.charAt(0);

  if (num != 'B' && num != 'E') {
    $("input[name=NCF_606]").after('<div class="alert alert-info">Debe comenzar por B o E el NCF</div>');
    this.focus();
  } else {
    if (this.value.length < 11) {
      $("input[name=NCF_606]").after('<div class="alert alert-warning">Debe Tener 11 digitos</div>');
      this.focus();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="NCF_606" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Nuevo código funciona pero esta como complicado.

```
    $("input[name=NCF_606]").on('input', function () {
$(".alert").remove(); 

    var Ncaracteres = $(this);

    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^BE0-9]/g,'');

     num=this.value.charAt(0);

  if(num!='B' && num!='E'){
    $("input[name=NCF_606]").after('<div class="alert alert-danger">Debe comenzar por B o E el NCF</div>');

      this.focus();
  }else{
        if(num =='B'){
            Ncaracteres.prop('maxLength', 11);
            if(this.value.length!=11){
                $("input[name=NCF_606]").after('<div class="alert alert-info">Debe Tener 11 digitos</div>');
                this.focus();

                } 

        } 
        if(num == 'E'){
            Ncaracteres.prop('maxLength', 13);
            if(this.value.length!=13){
                $("input[name=NCF_606]").after('<div class="alert alert-info">Debe Tener 13 digitos</div>');
                this.focus();

                } 


        }

}


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inades RD.

Buen día, veo que estas utilizando if y una expresión regular, a lo mejor requieres extender tu ciclo if,en la forma `if{} else if {} else {}` es solo una idea.

Lo que creo que debes hacer es detectar el primer carácter y en base a este aplicar la expresión regular que te valide la entrada de determinado numero de dígitos, si es B que acepte 11 dígitos yo utilizo este esquema para determinar la cantidad de dígitos a capturar `var expreg =/^[0]{4}[0-9]{8}[0-9]{4}$/;`, de esta manera tu expresión regular podría quedar así `/^[B]{1}[0-9]{11}$/ y  /^[E]{1}[0-9]{13}$/` y solo va aceptar esa "cadena" de caracteres.

Te dejo la siguiente pagina web donde puedes generar tus expresiones regulares y realizar la prueba en linea [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).

Espero sea de tu ayuda mi contribución.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Te paso este codigo:

```
        $("input[name=NCF_606]").bind({
            change: function() {
                cambiaLargo($(this).attr("id"))
            }
        });

        function cambiaLargo(idTextBox){
            var codigoLetra = $(idTextBox).val().substring(0,1);
            var largo = 10;
            if(codigoLetra == "X"){
                largo = 4;
            }else if(codigoLetra == "Y"){
                largo = 8;
            }
            $(idTextBox).attr("maxlength": "4");
        }
```

Yo enlazo el `DOM` con `bind`, pero funcionaria igual con `on`

Para evitar la introducción de caracteres no deseados con el evento `keypress` y el metodo `keyCode()` lo puedes hacer perfectamente y sin muchas complicaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Hola que tal intenta con esto:

```
document.getElementById('NCF_606').addEventListener('keypress', validarTecla);
```

esto hace que se registre un evento al presionar la tecla para llamar a la funcion `validarTecla()` para hacer la comprobacion de que no exista en el input la letra **E** ni la letra **B**

```js
function addMax(argument,length) {
        if (argument=="B"){
            $("input[name=NCF_606]").attr("maxlength",13).attr("minlength",13);
            if (length<13) 
                $("input[name=NCF_606]").after('<div class="alert alert-warning">Debe Tener 13 digitos</div>');
                this.focus();
        }
        else if(argument=="E"){
            $("input[name=NCF_606]").attr("maxlength",11).attr("minlength",11)
            if (length<11) 
                $("input[name=NCF_606]").after('<div class="alert alert-warning">Debe Tener 11 digitos</div>');
                this.focus();
        }

    }
    $("input[name=NCF_606]").on('input', function() {
        $(".alert").remove();
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^BE0-9]/g, '');
        num = this.value.charAt(0);
        if (num != 'B' && num != 'E') {
            $("input[name=NCF_606]").after('<div class="alert alert-info">Debe comenzar por B o E el NCF</div>');
            this.focus();
        } else {
            addMax(num,this.value.length)
        }
    });

    function validarTecla(event) {
        if((event.target.value.toUpperCase().indexOf('E')>=0 || event.target.value.toUpperCase().indexOf('B')>=0)
            && (event.key.toUpperCase() === 'E' || event.key.toUpperCase() === 'B') ){
            event.preventDefault();
    }

}

document.getElementById('NCF_606').addEventListener('keypress', validarTecla);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="NCF_606" name="NCF_606" />
```